# Is there a "best practice" matrix convention for openGL shaders (GLSL)

Tags: opengl, shader, vertex-shader

So there is a difference between "column major" and "row major" matrix notation conventions, which everyone seems to say "pick the one you like". OpenGL seems to want it's input matrices represented in memory as "column major" and there is the difference between pre-multiply and post-multiply.

So in a typical 3d graphics system you have transforms for:

modelSourceVertex -> ModelToWorld -> WorldToEye(Camera) -> CameraToClip(projection to 2x2x2 cube) -> ClipToPixels ( to 2d vertices in pixel device space internal to GL set by "viewport" )

One tends to precalculate the sequences that do not change much ie: WorldToClip to optimize.

I see in shaders a number of things.

```
mat4 MVP = Model * Projection;
gl_Position = modelPosition * MVP;
# **********
gl_position = Projection * Model * modelPosition;
# **********
mat4 MVP = ModelMatrix * ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix;
gl_Position = modelPosition * MVP;
# **********
etc
```

Many of those "crowd sourced" samples seem to be naive and often ModelToWorld and WorldToEye are identity or simply rotated so they will work even if the matrix math is ordered improperly.

My question is, is there a "proper" or "most widely accepted" convention ?

In a world where shader libraries are becoming more common I want to adhere to the "best" way in our system.

Comment: I think just having the single matrix input to the shader is simplest and most common. Avoids unnecessary repeated math on the GPU: the CPU can do the multiply of the matrices once per draw call, but the GPU would be doing a redundant multiply for every vertex it shades, which isn't good.

Comment: I agree but sometimes a shader will want intermediate results of the interpolated vertices in which case you want the matrices present as attributes or uniforms  Often just ModelToWorld and WorldToClip.

Comment: @Andrea seem proper - though I would hope a shader compiler would be smart enough to cache the "MVP" if the source attributes have not be reloaded. Though surely easy enough to do at the time they are reloaded on the CPU side.

Comment: @peterk: "*I see in shaders a number of things.*" Prove it. I especially want to see an example of where you found the third.